# Why did my back button focus stop working?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, equipment-damage

I was shooting at a styled shoot last week. Everything was going well. Then all of a sudden while I was shooting my back button focus stopped working. It didn’t seem like it was even trying to find focus whereas just my shoot before it was nailing it every time. My camera body is a Nikon D750 and my lens is a 50mm 1.4 Nikon.

I went to my auto focus settings and the camera said “this option is not available with current camera settings or in cameras current state.”
It happened mid shooting. I hadn’t changed the autofocus on the lens or camera body. It was extremely bright. I don’t know if that changes anything?

I switched to manual focus which also did not work initially. I then turned the camera off and back on and then manual focus did work. I did not argue with it and just shot like that.

This has happened to me one other time. I thought I fixed it by remounting the lens and changing my focus point, but apparently not?

Any advice would help. There is a camera repair store in town so I'm planning to see if they can help but wanted to see if anyone on here has ever experienced this.

Comment: Have you tried to use AF again to see if back button AF is available again or still unavailable?

Comment: Can you assign autofocus to another control (eg. half shutter press) and what happens then? Or was the entire sub-menu unavailable? Have you tried resetting to factory settings?

Comment: In which shooting mode were you? Did you change the mode during the shooting? I know on my D750 I have the back button focusing enabled in U1/U2 modes but not in P/S/A/M modes. Also can you clarify what you mean by "manual focus did not work"?

Comment: What do you mean by manual focus did not work initially? I've never heard of that happening.

Comment: Is there a new Nikon 50/1.4 that is AF-P? Aren't all AF-P lenses *focus-by-wire*, even when using manual focus? That is, the input to the focusing ring provided by the user is translated to a control input sent to the camera body which, in turn, sends a movement instruction to the focus motor in the lens.